# Linear solve warning when simulating deformable object

Tags: drake

We are using the deformable_torus example in `examples/multibody/deformable_torus` modified to use the stanford bunny tetmesh (which we created using TetWild) where the bunny falls from some small hight. The simulation runs fine until the bunny hits the ground at which time we get the following error

[2022-11-28 18:43:40.215] [console] [warning] Linear solve did not converge in Newton iterations in FemSolver.

The simulation seems to stop working at that point and we just get a lot of the same repeated error. Is there a way to change the solver so that the simulation works?

We've tried reducing the number of points in the tetmesh but this seems to still break whenever the object hits the ground

Comment: That usually means that the time step being taken is too large given the mesh and the physical parameters. Could you provide more information to help triage the issue? For example, the size of the time step, the young's modulus and poisson ratio. Sharing the exact mesh that you are using would also be helpful.

Comment: The higher you drop the bunny and the stiffer the bunny is, the smaller the time step needs to be.

Comment: With smaller time step it does seem to work better but eventually fails when it collides with the following error

`[2022-12-05 18:36:22.817] [console] [warning] Linear solve did not converge in Newton iterations in FemSolver.
abort: Failure at multibody/contact_solvers/sap/sap_model.cc:391 in CalcDelassusDiagonalApproximation(): condition 'A_ldlt[c].eigen_linear_solver().isPositive()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
`

This is with timestep 1e-4 and young's modulus 5e3

Comment: Additionally here is a link to the mesh we're using
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1nb32520xl0ayex/small_bunny.vtk?dl=0

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. The root cause of the issue is the same -- a combination of  mesh conditioning, stiffness, and timestep. I understand that the time step of 1e-4s is already quite small. Here's an alternative attempt of meshing the bunny: https://gist.github.com/xuchenhan-tri/35c2fa868703e70be27ceeccc85de422. I'm able to run this with E=5e3 and dt=5e-4s. Future improvements should allow you to take much larger timesteps. Stay tuned!

Comment: This seems to fix the problem, could you share how you generated your tetmesh?

Comment: I first decimated the surface mesh with Houdini so that it's slightly coarser. (You can choose your favorite mesh editor). Then I used TetWild with the following flags `-l 0.1 --targeted-num-v 400`.